# Benefit to Wiring a Bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

We are doing a fairly complex project that hits multiple data sources.  Currently we are up to 64 web service transactions and anticipate adding more.  We have a service layer defined, and a DAO.  The service layer classes typically have one or more DAO classes that do the job of looking up data.  The DAO classes are wired into the service layer classes using spring xml wiring.

The DAO classes all have a an Interface and an Impl.  The key here is there is only ever one Impl.  While the impl might change, although even that is unlikely as the DAO layer comes from a stable, legacy system.

So what is the benefit of having spring wiring if there will only ever be one impl?  Why not just instantiate the class in the service layer classes?

Comment: So you can test the services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason is unit testing, you will not be able to isolate a class from its dependencies with mocks if the class instantiates them itself.

A benefit with using an interface is that Spring can create AOP proxies (eg for declarative transaction management) with JDK dynamic proxies, otherwise it will need CGLIB. From Spring docs - JDK dynamic proxies are preferred whenever you have a choice http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying  -

Comment: Good answer, so +1, however in our case we are not doing that.  Although we probably should be.

Comment: ok, added another reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are many good reasons to use it, even when you think its not needed.
I think this article sums them up pretty good.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/dependency-injection/dependency-injection-benefits.html

Answer (score 0):

Your DAO might need other configuration than just the implementing class (data source URL, connection pool parameters etc.). In the philosophy of dependency injection, such details should be kept out of the code because they constitute configuration. The service class should contain strictly business logic.

Having said that, there has been a backlash against XML-based configuration descriptors in favor of in-code metadata, like so:

```
@Inject
private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
```

This will cause Spring to inject a CustomerDAOImpl automatically, as long as it is the only CustomerDAO implementation it finds. The CustomerDAOImpl class may in turn have other annotations specifying all the necessary configuration details.